# How to write query in Spring Data JPA with multiple nullable parameters?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've got an Entity class like this :

```
class EntityClass {
    UUID id;
    String param1, param2, param3;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

My Service class will've some method like this to make use of all the columns like this, and I want to be able to handle all requests with the same repository method instead of writing multiple repository methods for each case where a combination of parameters is null.

```
class ServiceClass {
    List<EntityClass> getAllBy(List<String> param1, List<String> param2, String param3) {
        return repositoryInterface.customFindAll(param1, param2, param3);
    }
}
```

Now my repository class should've this method. But I want to be able to handle the case where any combination of {param1, param2, param3} can be null as in {param1 = null or empty, param2 != null, param3 != null} or {param1 = null or empty, param2 = null or empty, param3 != null} etc.

The repository method customFindAll should basically be able to search entity table to check if `param1` column value is in any of the lists of values sent etc. if not `null`.

So how should I handle the native query in spring JPA to do such a thing instead of creating different methods for different combinations?

```
interface RepositoryInterface extends JpaRepository<EntityClass, UUID> {
    @Query(value = "FILL THE QUERY", nativeQuery = true)
    List<EntityClass> customFindAll(@Param("param1") List<String> param1, @Param("param2") List<String> param2, @Param("param3") String param3)
}
```

Comment: if they are null why do you need to execute this method? even though in database there will be nothing to compare with `null`

Comment: @Deadpool Yea that's what I want to do - if my service method receives a list of values then search like param1 in :param1, but if it receives a null value for param1, don't serach for it.

Comment: Why don't you check them in service class?

Comment: @Deadpool As in check in service class and based on that call the appropriate repository method? If so, then I'll 've to create many repository methods - one for each combination, right?

Comment: When everything is not null then call that method, if something is null or empty don't call, i believe there is no use if any of them are null or empty

Comment: So if anything is NULL, then I've to call another method right? So for every combination of non null values, I'll 've to create a different method if I understand correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187445/discussion-between-user3248186-and-deadpool).

Answer (score 2):

The general approach to this is to use a where clause like this:

```
WHERE (:param1 IS NULL OR param1 IN :param1) ...
```

But I don't think you can do a `is null` check on a list-valued bind parameter. 
But you can [use SpEL expressions for this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions).

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT id, param1, param2, param3
FROM EntityClass
WHERE (:#{#param1 == null ? 0 : 1} = 0 OR param1 IN :param1) 
AND   (:#{#param2 == null ? 0 : 1} = 0 OR param2 IN :param2) 
AND   (:#{#param3 == null ? 0 : 1} = 0 OR param3 IN :param3)
```

The comment is probably right: `IN` on an empty or `null` parameter might just not parse as a legal SQL statement. 
In that case you can use even more SpEL force (repeat three times as above):

```
( param1 IN :#{(#param1 == null || #param1.isEmpty()) ? java.util.Collections.singletonList(#param1) : #param1})
```

Of course, all this gets rather ugly, so you might be better of [creating your query dynamically using Specifications](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

Comment: but if :param1 is NULL or an empty list, won't it try to check in NULL or () which raises an error?